# How to generate PDF in Django in other than English?

Tags: python, django, pdf, render, html-helper

i am trying to generate pdf using xhtml2pdf in django for other than english  but it shows black square boxes and unusual texts.
i am trying to render nepali text in my pdf but i m getting this issue, can anyone help me to solve this issue ,,

```py
import imp
from io import StringIO

# from weasyprint import HTML
from django.template.loader import render_to_string
import tempfile
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.conf import settings
import datetime

# A stream implementation using an in-memory bytes buffer
# It inherits BufferIOBase

from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.template.loader import get_template


from xhtml2pdf import pisa  # a html2pdf converter


def render_to_pdf(template_src, context_dict={}):
    """
    This method will converts the template file into pdf
    @params template_src is the template file to be converted
    @params context_dict is the dictionary containing all the data written into the template
    """
    template = get_template(template_src)
    context_dict.update(
        {
            "invoice_title": context_dict["invoice_title"]
            + str(datetime.datetime.now())
            + ".pdf"
        }
    )
    # this will render the html template and parse the data into the template
    html = template.render(context_dict)
    # result = StringIO()
    response = HttpResponse(content_type="application/pdf")
    response["Content-Disposition"] = (
        "inline;attachment; filename="
        + context_dict["invoice_title"]
        + str(datetime.datetime.now())
        + ".pdf"
    )
    response["Content-Transfer-Encoding"] = "utf8"

    # part will create the pdf.
    # pdf = pisa.pisaDocument(BytesIO(html.encode("ISO-8859-1")), result)
    pisa_status = pisa.pisaDocument(html.encode("UTF-8"), response)

    # pisa_status= pisa.CreatePDF(
    #     html, dest=response
    # )
    if pisa_status.err:
        return HttpResponse("We had some errors <pre>" + html + "</pre>")
    return response
```

html template:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Purchase Invoice</title>
    <style>
        .heading {
            font-size: 12px;
            font-display: bold;
            text-align: center;
            padding-top: 50px;
        }
        
        .subheading {
            font-size: 12px;
            text-align: center;
        }
        
        .col-12 {
            width: 100%;
            float: left;
        }
        
        .col-3 {
            width: 25%;
            float: left;
        }
        
        .col-6 {
            width: 50%;
            float: left;
        }
        
        .textalignright {
            text-align: right;
            font-size: 12px;
        }
        
        .detail {
            font-size: 12px;
            /* font-weight: bold; */
        }
        
        table,
        th,
        td {
            border: 1px solid black;
            border-collapse: collapse;
            padding: 3px 3px 0px 3px;
        }
        
        .w-5 {
            width: 10%;
        }
        
        .w-25 {
            width: 50%;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="Company_profile">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12 heading">
                    <h1 class="text-white">{{request.user.company.print_name}}</h1>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <table style="width:100%; border:none;">
                    <tr style="border:none;">
                        <td style="width:33.33%; border:none;"></td>
                        <td style="width:33.33%; border:none; text-align:center;">Email : {{request.user.company.email}}
                        </td>
                        <td style="width:33.33%; border:none; text-align:right;">Times Printed :1</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr style="border:none;">
                        <td style="width:33.33%; border:none;"></td>
                        <td style="width:33.33%; border:none; text-align:center;">VAT Registration No: {{request.user.company.it_pan}}</td>
                        <td style="width:33.33%; border:none; text-align:right;">Copy of Original</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12 subheading">
                    <h3 class="float-left">कर बिजक</h3>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="Customer_info">
            <div class="row">
                <table style="width:100%; border:none;">
                    <tr style="border:none;">
                        <td style="width:50%; border:none;" class="detail">Invoice No.:{{purchase_data.voucherno}}</td>
                        <td style="width:50%; border:none; text-align:right;" class="detail">Invoice Date :{{purchase_data.formatted_nepalidate}}</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr style="border:none;">
                        <td style="width:50%; border:none;" class="detail">Customer Name:{{purchase_data.party.name}}</td>
                        <td style="width:50%; border:none;"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr style="border:none;">
                        <td style="width:50%; border:none;" class="detail">Customer Address :{{purchase_data.party.address}}</td>
                        <td style="width:50%; border:none;"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr style="border:none;">
                        <td style="width:50%; border:none;" class="detail">Customer's VAT/PAN No:{{purchase_data.party.it_pan}}</td>
                        <td style="width:50%; border:none;"></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
        <br />
        <br />
        <div class="Sales_detail">
            <table style="width:100%;">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th class="w-5">S.N</th>
                        <th class="w-25">Particulars</th>
                        <th class="w-5">Qty</th>
                        <th class="w-5">Unit </th>
                        <th class="w-5"> Price</th>
                        <th class="w-5">Amount</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    {% for purchaseItem in purchase_items %}
                    <tr>
                        <td scope="row">{{ forloop.counter }}</th>
                        <td>{{purchaseItem.item.name}}</td>
                        <td>{{purchaseItem.quantity}}</td>
                        <td>{{purchaseItem.unit.name}}</td>
                        <td>{{purchaseItem.formatted_price}}</td>
                        <td>{% if purchase_data.is_line_discount %}{{purchaseItem.formatted_amount}}{% else %}{{purchaseItem.formatted_amount}}{% endif %}</td>
                    </tr>
                    {% endfor %}
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="5" style="text-align:left;">Total Amount</td>
                        <td>{{purchase_data.total_amount}}</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="5" style="text-align:left;">Discount Amount</td>
                        <td>{{purchase_data.trade_discount_amount}}</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="5" style="text-align:left;">Total Taxable Amount</td>
                        <td>{{purchase_data.taxable_amount}}</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="5" style="text-align:left;">13% VAT</td>
                        <td>{{purchase_data.vat_amount}}</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="5" style="text-align:left; font-weight:Bold;">Total NPR Incl. VAT</td>
                        <td style="font-weight:Bold;">{{purchase_data.total_amount_inc_vat}}</td>

                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12 detail">
                    <p><b>Total Amount in Words :</b> {{purchase_data.formatted_amountwords}}
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="footer" style="margin-top:100px ;">
            <table style="width:100%; border:none;">
                <tr style="border:none;">
                    <td style="width:100%; border:none;">
                        <p class="text-left">(E. & O. E) Goods once sold are not exchangeable or returnable.</p>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr style="border:none;">
                    <td style="width:50%; border:none;"></td>
                    <td style="width:50%; border:none; text-align:right;">-----------------------------</td>
                </tr>
                <tr style="border:none;">
                    <td style="width:50%; border:none;"></td>
                    <td style="width:50%; border:none; text-align:right;">Authorised Signatory</td>
                </tr>
                <tr style="border:none;">
                    <td style="width:50%; border:none;"></td>
                    <td style="width:50%; border:none; text-align:right;">Printed On : {{purchase_data.formatted_nepalidate}}</td>
                </tr>
                <tr style="border:none;">
                    <td style="width:50%; border:none;"></td>
                    <td style="width:50%; border:none; text-align:right;">Printed By: {{request.user.username}}</td>
                </tr>
            </table>

        </div>

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I am getting this output with black square but not the text:

[image: Error-screenshot]

Comment: Likely the font does not support these characters...

Comment: This is not related to django but with xhtml2pdf. I am not familiar with the package xhtml2pdf, but check documentation for ["Asian font support"](https://xhtml2pdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference.html#asian-fonts-support).